# What happens to the Response If I close the browser tab

Tags: web, browser, request

Am having doubt about response generated for request if we close the requested browser tab.

As I know when we request to the Server for some resource or some action,Browser will receive the response from server.

Questions :

```
1, What will happen to the response generated by Server if I close the Browser.

2,I knew request will be identified by browser and cookies .
 Even if close the tab other tabs and browser is alive.
 So Response from Server can reach.
```

Please help me to understand what happens to the request and how it will be handled by browser and Server.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. I don't know alot about the subject but I believe it may ALSO depend on the browser. Like in chrome every tab is a separate process so if you close that or the browser I am sure it ends that process and the browser won't render or process that response. Hopefully the url in the bottom helps.

http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/

Comment: Thanks for reply.but I couldn't find anthing related to the response when requeste tab is not alive.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't much help. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for helpful to understand the browser and request.